How to create azure application insights teams alerts using terraform?
I need to receive alerts on teams channel every time an error occurs on three applications. How to create the alerts using terraform and how to send them to the teams channel? I'm new to the cloud developpement and also to terraform, what are the different steps to follow?

I think you're looking for Log Search Alert + Azure Action Group & webhook action.

I guess, you must have something which is able to send messeges(webhooks),
you can start here Azure Action Groups. In your case you might need webhook_receiver

thank you, the links you shared here helped me to start.
